Why does "Deutschland den Deutschen" mean "German for the Germans"?
I am not trying to stir up any political drama, I just had a question about the grammar. There was a viral video recently of Germans singing "Deutschland den Deutschen" which was translated to "Germany for the Germans."
I know that Deutschland means Germany, Deutschen means Germans and den is the accusative form of the. Is "Deutschland den Deutschen" short for "Deutschland ist für den Deutschen"? I'm not sure if den is the right the here.

"Drei Ringe den Elbenkönigen hoch im Licht /
Sieben den Zwergenherrschern in ihren Hallen aus Stein /
Den Sterblichen, ewig dem Tode verfallen, neun /
Einer dem Dunklen Herrn auf dunklem Thron /
Im Lande Mordor, wo die Schatten drohn."

"Ist dir das zu kompliziert? Das muss dir nicht peinlich sein" -- Equivalently: "Ist das zu kompliziert für dich? Das ist aber nicht peinlich für dich"

A better translation is probably Germany to the Germans.


Deutschland den Deutschen

It's not an accusative. Den Deutschen is dative plural, and in this example the dative case marks a dative object. The dative object tells who bears the result of an action. Usually, who benefits from it or who receives something:

Die Schotten haben den Deutschen gleich zu Beginn der EM einen Dämpfer verpasst.

Here's the Germans who received a beating.
And in your example it's the Germans who should receive Germany or benefit from it.

First off, "den Deutschen" is not Akkusativ. It is Dativ in Plural.
Dativ is the case for the recipient or the beneficiary of an action:

Ich gebe dir ...
Du hilfst mir ...
Das gehört ihm ...
Er schuldet ihr ...

This is a sort of a fixed phrase and a Verb like "gehört" (belongs to) or similar is implied. Here is an example in a less appalling and fascist context (the slogan is used by the far-right). Suppose cake is distributed:

Das erste Stück dem A, das zweite der B, das dritte den Brüdern C, ...

as you see the recipients are all in Dativ case. Here "bekommt" (gets), "wird gegeben" (is given to) or similar is implied.

Both of these answers are simplifying the complexity of this specific case, but the question also doesn't address the complexity. Let me try explaining:
Den Deutschen is actually also accusative, of the singular "Deutscher" it's one of those special cases where the noun actually gets an n in accusative. Another example for that is der Typ in accusative den Typen.

This is confusing because in this specific phrase the chant would only make sense as plural dative and that would translate to something on the lines of - Germany for the Germans or Germany belongs to the Germans.
I understand the confusion because you are looking at the word der and converting it to accusative without looking at the other words, den can also be plural dative but that usually (there are exceptions) comes with the noun also getting an n at the end, for example:
Der Baum in accusative becomes den Baum
Die Bäume (Plural) in dative becomes den Bäumen.
To add to this confusion there are exceptions of the accusative where the n is also added to the noun in the singular form, as I explained above.
The prepositions für is always followed with accusative so grammatically it would be perfectly correct to say "Deutschland für den Deutschen" and that would translate to Germany for the German, German meaning a person from Germany. The problem is that makes no sense, which German do you mean? It would make more sense to say "Deutschland für die Deutschen" which means Germany for the Germans, plural. It just sounds way more naive, and actually nicer to use the dative here instead of using the preposition für, especially since this is a very old phrase.
Here are some more examples of using the dative in this way:

